# .NET Core MvcRazorCompileOnPublish .Views.dll v .PrecompiledViews.dll

Tags: razor, model-view-controller, .net-core, precompiled-views

I have created a blank .NET Core 2.2 project and immediately published it. This is my published content:

[image]

If I now add the following into my .csproj:

```
<MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>true</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>
```

Then publish again, I get the following published content:

[image]

I cannot find an explanation anywhere for what the difference is between WebApplication3.Views.dll and WebApplication3.PrecompiledViews.dll. They both look like a library of precompiled views to me. If that's the case, what's the point of the config setting?